# Definition of a mathematical interval, why not defined this easier way?

Tags: definition, real-numbers

According to Wikipedia,

> *"In mathematics, a (real) interval is a set of real numbers with the property that any number that lies between two numbers in the set is also included in the set"*

If we are using terms like *"lying between two numbers"*, then why not define it as follows?

> *"Interval (bounded) is a set of numbers which contains all real numbers between two given numbers."*
>
> *"An unbounded interval is a set of numbers which contains all real numbers greater than (or less than) a certain number,"*

(And then specify closed and open intervals meaning)

Comment: Because we also want unbounded intervals.

Comment: @quasi, thanks, please see the edit.

Comment: Your definition of an unbounded interval is incorrect.  Think of the set which consists of $-1$ and all the positive reals.  That passes your test but it is not an interval.

Comment: @lulu, how? Which is your smaller number?

Comment: My set contains all real numbers greater than $0$, hence by your definition it is an unbounded interval.  But it does not contain $-.5$, say, despite the fact that it contains both $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @lulu, Thanks. I guess, that answers my question. Should I delete it?

Comment: Well, I think you can salvage your definition by replacing your "certain number" by "any element of the set".  (and you have to declare whether you want $>$ or $<$ in advance).  Still, I don't see the simplification of the standard definition...indeed you are forced to define bounded and unbounded intervals separately while the standard definition handles both cases.

Comment: @lulu. Yeah, I see. Nice. :)

Comment: Note the edit I made:  you have to specify "left" or "right" unbounded to avoid situations like the union of the reals $<-1$ and the reals $>1$.

Comment: The phrase "lying between" is meant to invoke the image of the real number line. In that case a "number" corresponds to a point on that line and an interval consists of two points and all of the points on the line between those two points.

Comment: Note: Most precalculus texts carefully define $9$ types of intervals:
$$(a,b),\;\;\;[a,b],\;\;\;[a,b),\;\;\;(a,b]$$
$$(-\infty,b),\;\;\;(-\infty,b],\;\;\;(a,\infty),\;\;\;[a,\infty)$$
$$(-\infty,\infty)$$
The Wiki article is just trying to specify a simple criterion that covers all $9$ types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly convoluted definitions usually exist because they're equivalent to the more intuitive versions and because experience dictates that they're easier to use in proofs (and/or less verbose).

For example, by not having cases the former definition you gave makes it easy to check when a subset happens to be a subinterval. You only have to examine that one property. Moreover, to some degree it is constructive in that it naturally lends itself to constructing the minimal (by inclusion) interval containing a set of points.

Your second definition has just enough complexity to make even those simple proofs a little annoying, and once you get the details worked out so that it's actually correct you'll be able to show the first is equivalent to the second anyway. Why not have the definition be the easy to use in the first place?